# Exception thrown by deferred.await() within a runBlocking treated as unhandled even after caught

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

This code:

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        try {
            val deferred = async { throw Exception() }
            deferred.await()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Caught $e")
        }
    }
    println("Completed")
}
```

results in this output:

```
Caught java.lang.Exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
    at org.mtopol.TestKt$main$1$deferred$1.invokeSuspend(test.kt:11)
    ...
```

This behavior doesn't make sense to me. The exception was caught and handled, and still it escapes to the top-level as an unhandled exception.

Is this behavior documented and expected? It violates all my intuitions on how exception handling is supposed to work.

I adapted this question from a thread on the [Kotlin forum](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/migration-to-coroutines-from-0-25-1-to-0-30-2/10158).

---

The Kotlin docs suggest using `supervisorScope` if we don't want to cancel all coroutines when one fails. So I can write

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        supervisorScope {
            try {
                launch {
                    delay(1000)
                    println("Done after delay")
                }
                val job = launch {
                    throw Exception()
                }
                job.join()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Caught $e")
            }
        }
    }
    println("Completed")
}
```

The output is now

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception
    at org.mtopol.TestKt$main$2$1$job$1.invokeSuspend(test.kt:16)
    ...
    at org.mtopol.TestKt.main(test.kt:8)
    ...

Done after delay
Completed
```

This, again, is not be the behavior I want. Here a `launch`ed coroutine failed with an unhandled exception, invalidating the work of other coroutines, but they proceed uninterrupted.

The behavior I would find reasonable is to spread cancellation when a coroutine fails in an unforeseen (i.e., unhandled) manner. Catching an exception from `await` means that there wasn't any global error, just a localized exception that is handled as a part of the business logic.

Comment: When I run your code I get: `Caught java.lang.Exception
Completed`... which version exactly are you using?

Comment: The current version, Kotlin 1.3 with kotlinx.coroutines 1.0

Comment: I am rather a beginner regarding coroutines, but maybe someone can enlighten me... why didn't you place the `try/catch` within the `async`? You could then call `coroutineContext.cancel()` within the `catch` (from within the `async`)? (Wondering why the `cancel()` doesn't really allow to propagate any information from the cancelling coroutine to the parent.) Or did you use your construct to catch all possible exceptions of any async calls with a single catch? But then: doesn't the exception handler for `launch` suffice for such a use case?

Comment: Handling the exception within `async` may be inappropriate to the use case. Maybe I want to get some other async results in the meantime, as a prerequisite to being able to handle the exception. The `async` call may also be a part of a library not under my control.

Comment: but using the exception handler would also work here, right? You could throw the exception and just handle it in the handler...

Comment: If a library function makes the `async` call, there's nothing more i can do about it. If it fails, it will break the surrounding scope. And if i need some other async results before i can write the handling logic, i can't provide the exception handler ahead of time.

Comment: Totally agree to the question. Although catching all errors even in coroutines that are not awaited or joined seems useful, it would be good if the errors simply bubble up if it gets awaited. Hopefully someone making that design decision can shed some light on it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After studying the reasons why Kotlin introduced this behavior I found that, if the exceptions weren't propagated this way, it would be complicated to write well-behaved code that gets cancelled in a timely fashion. For example:

```
runBlocking {
    val deferredA = async {
        Thread.sleep(10_000)
        println("Done after delay")
        1
    }
    val deferredB = async<Int> { throw Exception() }
    println(deferredA.await() + deferredB.await())
}
```

Because `a` is the first result we happen to wait for, this code would keep running for 10 seconds and then result in an error and no useful work achieved. In most cases we'd like to cancel everything as soon as one component fails. We could do it like this:

```
val (a, b) = awaitAll(deferredA, deferredB)
println(a + b)
```

This code is less elegant: we're forced to await on all results at the same place and we lose type safety because `awaitAll` returns a list of the common supertype of all arguments. If we have some

```
suspend fun suspendFun(): Int {
    delay(10_000)
    return 2
}
```

and we want to write

```
val c = suspendFun()
val (a, b) = awaitAll(deferredA, deferredB)
println(a + b + c)
```

We're deprived of the opportunity to bail out before `suspendFun` completes. We might work around like this:

```
val deferredC = async { suspendFun() }
val (a, b, c) = awaitAll(deferredA, deferredB, deferredC)
println(a + b + c)
```

but this is brittle because you must watch out to make sure you do this for each and every suspendable call. It is also against the Kotlin doctrine of "sequential by default"

In conclusion: the current design, while counterintuitive at first, does make sense as a practical solution. It additionally strengthens the rule not to use `async-await` unless you're doing parallel decomposition of a task.

Answer (score 2):

Though all the answers are right at there place but let me throw some more light in it that might help other users. It is documented [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/exception-handling.md#cancellation-and-exceptions) ([Official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#cancellation-and-exceptions)) that:-

> If a coroutine encounters exception other than `CancellationException`,
>   it cancels its parent with that exception. This behaviour cannot be
>   overridden and is used to provide stable coroutines hierarchies for
>   [structured concurrency](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/composing-suspending-functions.md#structured-concurrency-with-async) which do not depend on
>   [CoroutineExceptionHandler](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-coroutine-exception-handler/index.html) implementation. The original exception is
>   handled by the parent (In GlobalScope) when all its children terminate.
>
> It does not make sense to install an exception handler to a coroutine
>   that is launched in the scope of the main [runBlocking](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html), since the main
>   coroutine is going to be always cancelled when its child completes
>   with exception despite the installed handler.

Hope this will help.

Comment: In other hand, [the docs hint](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/exception-handling.md#exception-propagation) that `async` exceptions are not propagated to their parents. I find it misleading.

Comment: @YamashiroRion I absolutely agree. Catching and then **also** canceling the parent? They should definitely mention this quirky behavior in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

This can be resolved by slightly altering the code to make the `deferred` value be executed explicitly using the same `CoroutineContext` as the `runBlocking` scope, e.g.

```
runBlocking {
    try {
        val deferred = withContext(this.coroutineContext) {
            async {
                throw Exception()
            }
        }
        deferred.await()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        println("Caught $e")
    }
}
println("Completed")
```

**UPDATE AFTER ORIGINAL QUESTION UPDATED**

Does this provide what you want:

```
runBlocking {
    supervisorScope {
        try {
            val a = async {
                delay(1000)
                println("Done after delay")
            }
            val b = async { throw Exception() }
            awaitAll(a, b)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Caught $e")
            // Optional next line, depending on whether you want the async with the delay in it to be cancelled.
            coroutineContext.cancelChildren()
        }
    }
}
```

This is taken from [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/753#issuecomment-433404643) comment which discusses parallel decomposition.

Comment: Yes, I tried out this variation before posting. Replacing the `async-await` pair with just `withContext` also restores the expected behavior.

Comment: This is discussed in a lot of detail in issues [753](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/753) and [763](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/763) in the kotlinx.coroutines github repo.  My suggestion and @marstran's suggestion are both made as ways around this.  Interestingly they also refer to this as "async's astonishing behavior" :-)  The upshot of 763 is that an issue has been logged to better document this behaviour, namely "async.await cancelling outer scope" (issue [787](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/787)).

Comment: Yes, this can be simplified to `try { awaitAll(a, b) } catch (e: Exception) { coroutineContext.cancelChildren() }`. This is a workaround that first disables the default behavior and then re-implements on its own the cancellation spreading. It accentuates the problem with the default behavior, which automagically runs this `try awaitAll - cancelChildren` idiom in the background with no regard to my handling logic.

Answer (score 0):

A normal `CoroutineScope` (which is created by `runBlocking`) immediately cancels all child coroutines when one of them throws an exception. This behaviour is documented here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#cancellation-and-exceptions

You can use a `supervisorScope` to get the behaviour you want. If a child coroutine fails inside a supervisor scope, it will not immediately cancel the other children. The children will only be cancelled if the exception is unhandled.

For more info, see here: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html

```
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        supervisorScope {
            try {
                val deferred = async { throw Exception() }
                deferred.await()
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("Caught $e")
            }
        }
    }
    println("Completed")
}
```

Comment: I don't actually want the behavior where coroutines aren't cancelled when one of them throws an exception. I'd expect all the coroutines to be cancelled due to an _unhandled_ exception in one of them. This behavior, where i explicitly take care of the exception and yet it escapes to the top level, seems broken.

Comment: The `supervisorScope` _will_ cancel all children if the exception is unhandled. I'll edit the text to make that more clear ;)

Comment: It will cancel the children only if the `supervisorScope`'s block throws it, but it won't do anything if the exception escapes unhandled from a nested `launch` block or any other block that starts another coroutine.

Comment: Hmm, it works exactly as I expect in my tests here. Could you provide a code example that doesn't work as you expect?

Comment: I provided it as an addition to the question.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Ah, that happens because `launch` propagates exceptions differently than `async`, as is documented here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html#exception-propagation. You would want that first `launch` to be canceled when the second one fails, right?

Comment: More broadly, that is the behavior I assumed would be present. Propagate cancellation when one coroutine fails in a way that isn't explicitly dealt with. This is what you need for parallel decomposition, not just any old exception destroying your entire setup. Catching and handling an exception doesn't count as a failure.