# Kotlin coroutine can't handle exception

Tags: exception, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was playing around with coroutines and found some very strange behavior. I want to convert some asynchronous requests in my project using `suspendCoroutine()`. Here's piece of code showing this problem.

In first case, when suspend function is being called in `runBlocking` coroutine, exception from continuation goes to catch block, and then `runBlocking` finishes successfully. But in second case, when creating new `async` coroutine, exception goes through catch block and crashes the whole program.

```
package com.example.lib

import kotlinx.coroutines.async
import kotlinx.coroutines.runBlocking
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

object Test {
    fun runSuccessfulCoroutine() {
        runBlocking {
            try {
                Repository.fail()
            } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                println("Catching ex in runSuccessfulCoroutine(): $ex")
            }
        }
    }

    fun runFailingCoroutine() {
        runBlocking {
            try {
                async { Repository.fail() }.await()
            } catch (ex: Throwable) {
                println("Catching ex in runFailingCoroutine(): $ex")
            }
        }
    }
}

object Repository {
    suspend fun fail(): Int = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        cont.resumeWithException(RuntimeException("Exception at ${Thread.currentThread().name}"))
    }
}


fun main() {
    Test.runSuccessfulCoroutine()
    println()

    Test.runFailingCoroutine()

    println("We will never get here")
}
```

That's what is printed on console:

```
Catching ex in runSuccessfulCoroutine(): java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception at main

Catching ex in runFailingCoroutine(): java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception at main
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception at main
    at com.example.lib.Repository.fail(MyClass.kt:32)
    at com.example.lib.Test$runFailingCoroutine$1$1.invokeSuspend(MyClass.kt:22)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:32)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(Dispatched.kt:236)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.kt:123)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:69)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:45)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:35)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.lib.Test.runFailingCoroutine(MyClass.kt:20)
    at com.example.lib.MyClassKt.main(MyClass.kt:41)
    at com.example.lib.MyClassKt.main(MyClass.kt)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any ideas why this is happening - is it a bug, or am i using coroutines the wrong way?

**Update:**

Using `coroutineScope { ... }` will mitigate problem in `runFailingCoroutine()`

```
fun runFailingCoroutine() = runBlocking {
    try {
        coroutineScope { async { fail() }.await()  }
    } catch (ex: Throwable) {
        println("Catching ex in runFailingCoroutine(): $ex")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behavior of your second example is correct, this is the work of structured concurrency.
Because the inner `async` block throws an exception, this coroutine is cancelled. Due to structured concurrency the parent job is cancelled as well.

Look at this small example:

```
val result = coroutineScope {
    async {
        throw IllegalStateException()
    }
    10
}
```

This block will never return a value, even if we never request the `async` result. The inner coroutine is cancelled and the outer scope is cancelled as well.

If you don't like this behavior you can use the `supervisorScope`. In this case the inner coroutine can fail without failing the outer coroutine.

```
val result = supervisorScope {
    async {
        throw IllegalStateException()
    }
    10
}
```

In your first example you catch the exception inside of the coroutine block, because of this, the coroutine exits normally.

For discussion of this topic see:

- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/552
- https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/763

Comment: Yeah, wasn't thinking about structured concurrency at all. More reading:
[Github issue Exception handling with structured concurrency (rx & async)](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/691)
and [Roman Elizarov's "Structured concurrency" medium post](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952)

Answer (score 6):

I got struck by this behavior just yesterday, [here's my analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53222045/exception-thrown-by-deferred-await-within-a-runblocking-treated-as-unhandled-e/53225965#53225965).

In a nutshell, this behavior is desired because `async` does not have the same purpose as in other languages. In Kotlin you should use it sparingly, only when you have to decompose a task into several subtasks that run in parallel.

Whenever you just want to write

```
val result = async { work() }.await()
```

you should instead write

```
val result = withContext(Default) { work() }
```

and this will behave the expected way. Also, whenever you have the opportunity, you should move the `withContext` call into the `work()` function and make it a `suspend fun`.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting analysys. Also, good point, that there souldn't be `async { ... }.await()` altogether. But originally i found this behaviour, when i needed to zip 3 parallel api calls into one object, and exception in one api call crashed whole app.

Comment: Yes, you have to put your three async calls into a `coroutineScope` builder so you have a separate scope that will get cancelled. Your master scope should use in its `override val coroutineContext` a `SupervisorJob()` instead of just `Job()`.

Comment: @AlexanderSitnikov is it ok to use `GlobalScope.asyinc{ ... }.await()` and why there shouldn't be `asying { ... }.await()` altogether?