# Kotlin async in coroutine: exception caught and still propagated?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am running a coroutine in a `SupervisorJob` with a try/catch block surrounding only the await calls. The exception from the async block gets caught by the try/catch, but it still gets propagated and the app crashes.

This is what I have:

```
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()).launch {
            val a = async {
                delay(500)
                throw Exception("excep a")
                2
            }
            val b = async {
                delay(500)
                3
            }
            try {
                println(a.await() + b.await())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println("exception: ${e.message}")
            }
        }
```

This is what I get (note that "excep a" gets caught):

```
exception: excep a
Exception in thread "DefaultDispatcher-worker-3 @coroutine#1" java.lang.Exception: excep a
    at com.example.app.AuthTest$co2$1$a$1.invokeSuspend(AuthTest.kt:314)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

Comment: Your `launch` is only a child of `supervisorJob` while not being one itself so it does get cancelled and rethrows exception thrown by `a`. Perhaps you want to have a `supervisorScope` nested inside your `launch`? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53240861/9241978

Comment: Also, you should pretty much always use either `coroutineScope` or `supervisorScope` with `async` because the proper way to use `async` is to parallelize a task and not fire off a long-running background job. Parallelizing a task means that it shouldn't complete before the child `async` tasks are done.

Answer (score 2):

The exception handling mechanism of supervisorJob and Job is not the same. For supervisory tasks, the transmission of exceptions can only be from the parent scope to the child scope, and the propagation direction of the exception is one-way. Therefore, it is necessary to handle exceptions by itself for monitoring the scope of opening the coroutine.

```kotlin
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()).launch(CoroutineExceptionHandler { _, throwable ->
        println("$throwable")
    }) {
        val a = async {
            delay(500)
            throw Exception("excep a")
            2
        }
        val b = async {
            delay(500)
            3
        }
        println(a.await() + b.await())
    }
```

This exception will be handled in the top-level Job

Answer (score 1):

`SupervisorJob` has `launch` as Top coroutine and both `async/await` are nested coroutines.

Nested `async/await` always propagated up via Job hierarchy even if you use try/catch.

`launch` as Top coroutine require CoroutineExceptionHandler.

Alternatively you can:

1. wrap both `async` and `try/catch` in `supervisorScope`
2. wrap both `async` and `try/catch` in `coroutineScope` inside `try/catch`. But in this case second `async` will be cancelled after exception is thrown

Answer (score -1):

You are creating a parent coroutine using *launch* builder having *IO* dispatcher and *SupervisorJob*. Then you are creating two children coroutines using *async* biulder. But remember the child coroutines do not inherit the Job from its parent. Each child coroutine creates their own Job. So to avoid app crashing and exception apply the same supervisorjob explicitly to each child as shown below.

```
 val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        val a = async(supervisorJob) {
            delay(500)
            throw Exception("excep a")
            2
        }
        val b = async(supervisorJob) {
            delay(500)
            3
        }
        try {
            println(a.await() + b.await())
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("exception: ${e.message}")
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your code is breaking Structured Concurrency. Child coroutines is inherit the Job from its parent by default, but if you add Job to context as you did in both async than  it breaks parent-child relation. More details - https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/1001#issuecomment-468704955 and especially https://elizarov.medium.com/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055

Comment: @mobiledevAlex in the above code ignore the outer coroutine created by  _CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch_. Coroutine _a_ and _b_ are children of _supervisorJob_ job so they are siblings. Moreover, child coroutine does not inherit Job from parent but creates its own one while inheriting other contextual elements.  In the example _a_ and _b_ create their own jobs which are the children of _supervisorJob_. You print/log Jobs of parent and child coroutines and check the results. Some examples can be found at [this](https://trickyworld.tech/job-vs-supervisorjob-in-coroutines-kotlin/) link.

Comment: Child coroutine creates its own Job AND inherit Job from parent but if you pass Job as Context than you override elements that would be otherwise inherited from a parent scope. It's not recommend to pass job as a parameter of coroutine builder (as context) because it's break Structured Concurrency. You can read it in article written by Kotlin Coroutines creator: https://elizarov.medium.com/coroutine-context-and-scope-c8b255d59055